# How to fetch data from multiple namespaces in a soap response using python: xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, soap, xml-parsing

How to fetch value of  through the correct xpath using python xml.etree.ElementTree

This is the 'soap.xml' file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <platformMsgs:documentInfo xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <platformMsgs:nsId>WEBSERVICES_3883026_SB1_103120188552030381995151284_f039e9cc</platformMsgs:nsId>
        </platformMsgs:documentInfo>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <searchResponse xmlns="urn:messages_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <platformCore:searchResult xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                <platformCore:status isSuccess="true"/>
                <platformCore:totalRecords>200</platformCore:totalRecords>
                <platformCore:pageSize>1000</platformCore:pageSize>
                <platformCore:totalPages>1</platformCore:totalPages>
                <platformCore:pageIndex>1</platformCore:pageIndex>
                <platformCore:searchId>WEBSERVICES_3883026_SB1_103120188552030381995151284_f039e9cc</platformCore:searchId>
            </platformCore:searchResult>
        </searchResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my code.

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    tree = ET.parse('soap.xml') 
    print  tree.findall('.//{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}platformCore')
```

But it return [] instead of value = '200'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the correct namespace (nsmap), then you can search easily using prefixes:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('soap.xml')
nsmap = {'platformCore': 'urn:core_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com'}
print (tree.findall('.//platformCore:totalRecords', nsmap)[0].text)
```

Returns:

```
200
```